# I Have a PHP DNS Lookup form which i am trying to use within wordpress and it will not actually bring back the results

Tags: php, wordpress, dns

This is the code that I am using for this form.

```
[php]

   $dns = "";
   $message = "";

if( $_POST["dns"] )
  {
     $dns = $_POST['dns'];
     $ips = gethostbynamel("$dns");
     foreach ($ips as $ip => $value)
        { $message = $message . $value . "<br>"; }
  }

[/php]

<form action="[php] $_PHP_SELF [/php]" method="POST">

 <table border="0">
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><b>DNS LOOKUP</B><br></td>
  <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Domain Name</td>
  <td><input type="text" value="[php] echo "$dns"; [/php]" name="dns"></td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Check"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>[php] echo $message; [/php]</td>
  <td></td>
   </tr>
 </table>

 </form>
```

Could anyone assist me, what i need to be changed to ensure that this actually begins to work within the wordpress site. It seems to work fine when it isnt within a wordpress page which is realyl frustrating.

Comment: `if( $_POST["dns"] )` forgot a function name there?

Answer (score 0):

remove double quotes

```
 $ips = gethostbynamel($dns);
```

Comment: The problem that i have actually having with the form is....
once a user enters a web address into the search DNS and then presses search there isnt anything coming back from the search. But when the form is in a separate page (not wordpress) it works, so is there anything that needs to be changed to ensure that it functions in wordpress?

Comment: function fixed_gethostbyname ($host) 
 {
    // Try the lookup as normal...
    $ip = gethostbyname($host);
    // ...but if it fails, FALSE is returned instead of the unresolved host
    if ($ip != $host) { return $ip; } else return false;
}

Comment: Do I also need to add ($ip != $host) { return $ip; } else return false; } into my coding somewhere? I don't see how that will fix it. Because it is working when its not attached to the wordpress page

Comment: set form name <form action="[php] $_PHP_SELF [/php]" method="POST" name="issue001">

Comment: still doesn't display anything on the page after submit I'm afraid

Comment: 4 hours on with looking at the code and between me and my colleague have got this to work in a way